# How do you combine multiple Rails SQL queries into a single query in rails?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

In my rails code, I need to run a query on a table based on a combination of the date of the records and votes that the record has received.  I accomplish it like the following in rails:

```
if params[:sort_by] == "default"
    objs1 = class_name.where("created_at between '#{Date.today - 7}' and '#{Date.today}' and net_votes > 0").order("net_votes DESC")
    objs2 = class_name.where("created_at between '#{Date.today - 30}' and '#{Date.today - 7}' and net_votes > 0").order("net_votes DESC")
    objs3 = class_name.where("created_at between '#{Date.today - 90}' and '#{Date.today - 30}' and net_votes > 0").order("net_votes DESC")
    objs4 = class_name.where("created_at < '#{Date.today - 90}' and net_votes > 0").order("net_votes DESC")
    objs = objs1 + objs2 + objs3 + objs4
```

Efficiencies aside, I can't use pagination on the combined query result not to mention that the code is very ugly.  what would be the right way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `order` for the sorting logic, not `where`:

```
order_by_sql = <<-SQL
CASE WHEN created_at between '#{Date.today - 7}' and '#{Date.today}' THEN 1
     WHEN created_at between '#{Date.today - 30}' and '#{Date.today - 7}' THEN 2
     WHEN created_at between '#{Date.today - 90}' and '#{Date.today - 30}' THEN 3
     ELSE 4
END
SQL

objs = class_name.where('net_votes > 0').order(order_by_sql)
```

Comment: Awesome, this resulted in 50% performance gain for the query.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things you can do to make this more elegant and perform better:

1) Encapsulate each of the conditions into a scope.  For example, net_vtoes > 0 is reusable:

```
def self.has_votes
  where("net_votes > 0")
end

def self.ordered 
  order("net_votes DESC")
end

def self.last_week
  where("created_at between '#{Date.today - 7}' and '#{Date.today}'")
end
```

2) Create a scope operator as suggested by Ryan Bates in this RailsCast to allow you to combine the where conditions in an OR fashion: http://railscasts.com/episodes/355-hacking-with-arel?view=asciicast.  This will then let you build a statement like this:

```
(MyClass.last_week | MyClass.last_month).has_votes.ordered
```

Comment: Since you aren't instantiating the models until after the query is built, this is not going to result in the desired sort order...

Comment: Why?  ordered is an active record scope and the `|` is a new operator that combines scopes with a SQL `OR` statement.  Maybe you are confusing this with the standard Array union operator?

Comment: Yes, but the ordered scope doesn't force the same ordering as desired.  The OP's code resulted in the records ordered by created in the past week, then past month, then 90 days, then everything else.  Your scope orders all of them just by the vote count (not sure where you took that from).